# How to apply shooting method to boundary value problem with Neumann's boundaries?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, algorithms

I have following boundary value problem with Neumann's boundaries

$$
\begin{cases}
  y'' = y + 8 + 3x(1 - x) \\
  y'(0) = -3 \\
  y'(1) = e - \frac{1}{e} + 3
\end{cases}
$$

I have tried to find in various sources how to solve this kind of problem, but all the sources I have found describe an algorithm for solving the boundary value problem for Dirichlet's boundaries.

I need some kind of clue as to how to apply Shooting method to this problem

Comment: You can find the general solution of the DE, then the boundary conditions give a linear system for the coefficients. If you use an elimination approach, using first the left boundary condition to remove one unknown coefficient, then solving for the right BC emulates the shooting approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. the general solution of the homogeneous equation $y''=y$ is given by $c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}.$
2. a special solution of the equation $y'' = y + 8 + 3x(1 - x)$ has the form $y_s(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C.$ Determine $A,B,C.$
3. the general solution of $y'' = y + 8 + 3x(1 - x)$ is given by $y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}+y_s(x).$ Now invoke the boundary conditions .

Comment: Thanks,  I have improved it